# Resharper reformat is changing line endings

Tags: resharper, eol

Is there a setting to change it so ReSharper leaves my line endings alone? Nothing is jumping out at me.

**Explanation of how I verified it below...**

It looks like when I use ReSharper and do a complete code cleanup, it will change my line endings to CRLF, regardless of what they were before.

I've proven this to myself by having a file open in VS2010, doing File -> Advanced Save Options and changing line style to Unix (LF)

In Notepad++ I turn on viewing line endings and see only LF at the end of the lines.

Then, I do a ReSharper code cleanup, and CRLF shows up everywhere.

Comment: Please file a bug report at http://youtrack.jetbrains.net

Comment: Done: http://youtrack.jetbrains.net/issue/RSRP-274916?projectKey=RSRP

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Under Resharper / Options / Code Editing / General Formatter Style / Default Line Ending Style  you can select - Current OS | Windows | Mac | Unix

Comment: This didn't exist before the bug fix here:
https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/RSRP-274916

It is now, 100% the right answer (back in 2012 when I asked this, there was sadly no right answer :) )

Answer (score 1):

[image: ReSharper configuration window]

Do not forget to also ensure your git settings are accurate for line endings. If you're like me, you ended up here because you keep your source code on a Mac and run Visual Studio within windows. You need to ensure your git settings also include the right "core.autocrlf" setting.

https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Customizing-Git-Git-Configuration

Comment: Those are excellent points, and if I could award dual correct answers I would, but the other answer was first.

Answer (score -4):

CRLF line ending is hard-coded in ReSharper since version 1.0.

The main reason for this - VS running under Windows, where CRLF ending is standard. Your project must have been very special to not use Windows defaults for text files

Comment: Nope, it's not so special :) We just interact with devs on OSX and Linux and I'd like everywhere to have the same line endings. Certain operations produce mixed EOL, and I happened to find ReSharper is one of them. I think they're addressing it in ReSharper 7.0 if I read that ticket right so it's all good.